# Appending and replacing the query string value of a data-* attribute URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, query-string

Using the following code:

```
<select id="data-values">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1234567890">Option 1</option>
    <option value="0987654321">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I am taking the value of this option element and append it as a query string to be an authorization code to a data attribute containing a service (which will be different URLs depending on whether on staging or production) in an element:

**URL1**

```
<div id="data-service" data-src="http://example.com/json_data/">Stylized service data here to be refreshed with new authorization code append</div>
```

I need to use jQuery to append a new query string and value to this url so that it looks like

**URL2**

```
<div id="data-service" data-src="http://example.com/json_data/?auth_code=1234567890">New stylized service data refreshed because of new auth code</div>
```

If an `auth_code` already exists when user selects new option value, it needs to then replace it with a new value:

**URL3**

```
<div id="data-service" data-src="http://example.com/json_data/?auth_code=0987654321">New stylized service data refreshed because of new auth code</div>
```

Changing this `auth_code` value will then expose new data from the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sheb3dvw/)

```
$('#data-values').on('change', function () {
    var url = "http://example.com/json_data/",
        value = this.value;

    if (value) {
        url += "?auth_code=" + value;
    }
    $('#data-service').attr('data-src', url);
});
```

..or without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7umoeLw/)

```
var select = document.querySelector('#data-values');
select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var url = "http://example.com/json_data/",
        value = this.value;

    if (value) {
        url += "?auth_code=" + value;
    }
    document.querySelector('#data-service').dataset.src = url;
});
```

Comment: The chance that there's an auth code query string to begin with is 50/50. This code assumes that the auth code value will already exist which it very well might not. Also, I added an ID to the elements to select them.

Comment: I guess I should also include that we're using a staging and production service URL so the URLs will vary depending on where you are. So I don't know if I can hardcode the URL into the variable of the function.

Comment: @micah It's still kinda unclear. You're saying that if an `auth_code` already exists, it needs to be replaced... but if an `auth_code` *doesn't* exist, nothing should happen? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: If `auth_code` doesn't exist, then when the option is selected that contains a value, that value needs to be appended to the `auth_code` query string and thus added to the end of the URL like in 2nd URL example. I edited my original text above to make that more clear.

Comment: Line 3 of your jQuery example doesn't seem to be replacing the data url attribute when I select a new option but I'm seeing that the value is appending to the URL from line 2 when I do a console log. :/

Comment: @micah Yea, that's a bug with version 1.7 of jQuery.. use `$('#data-service').attr('data-src', url)` instead. I updated the answer, but I still don't think that's what you want. In terms of the production/staging environments, could you use the URL that's already set in the `data-set` attribute rather than hardcoding it in the JS?

Comment: For the `url` variable, why can't I use `$('#data-service').data('src')`? I'm trying this one and it's trying to put it in a new attribute of just `src`.

Comment: Yes! Now I need to figure out why mine isn't working like yours! Thank you so much, this was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would save the original value of the URL (since it's probably generated by a server side script), and then append the query string if necessary (taking care to escape the values):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // take base url first
    var $service = $('#data-service'),
    baseServiceUrl = $service.data('src');

    $('#data-values').on('change', function() {
        var newUrl = baseServiceUrl;

        if (this.value.length) {
            newUrl += '?auth_code=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value);
        }
        $service
          .data('src', newUrl)
          .text(newUrl); // also change the element contents
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/wuzeqenefo/1/)